# How to access www version of Next.js static export site deployed with Docker and Nginx?

Tags: docker, nginx, next.js, dns, cloudflare

I have a Next.js static export [site](https://github.com/mansourlotfi/mansourlotfi) that I deployed with Docker and Nginx. I am using Cloudflare for DNS and SSL. I can access my site using https://mansourlotfi.ir, but when I try to access https://www.mansourlotfi.ir, I get a "404 page not found".

> Dockerfile

```
FROM hub.hamdocker.ir/nginx:1.22.0
COPY ./out ./project
RUN rm ../etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./nginx-configs ../etc/nginx/conf.d
```

> settings.conf inside nginx-configs folder

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mansourlotfi.ir;
    return 301 https://mansourlotfi.ir$request_uri;
}

server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name c13.hamravesh.hamserver.ir;
    return 301 https://mansourlotfi.ir$request_uri;
}

server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name mansourlotfi.ir;
    root /project;

    location /
    {
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html
    {
        internal;
    }

}
```

> cloudflare DNS config

[image]

Note: I have already added CNAME records for both example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) in Cloudflare, pointing to the same IP address of my server.

also when I visit a non-existing route such as example.com/asd, instead of showing the Next.js 404 page, it shows me the homepage.
I have read all the topics related to this issue in the community, but unfortunately, I was unsuccessful. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have not included server block properly

here you can change your setting.conf

```
   server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.mansourlotfi.ir c13.hamravesh.hamserver.ir;
        return 301 https://mansourlotfi.ir$request_uri;
    }
    
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mansourlotfi.ir;
        root /project;
    
        location / {
            index index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }
    
        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
            internal;
        }
    }
```

Make sure you settings.conf file inside the nginx-configs folder and rebuild and redeploy your Docker container to apply the changes.

Comment: Nope . You just copied the text of my question and did not pay attention. thank you But this is not the answer

Answer (score 0):

All settings for the www version in Dockerfile, Cloudflare, and nginx were correct. Another thing was missing: I had to add my domain with www to the host settings that run my containerized app.
[image]

this solved my problem and now i can see my site with www.